# Django get_absolute_url NoReverseMatch zero patterns tried

Tags: python, django

I've been trying for days now to use get_absolute_url and whenever I click on the view on site button in the admin page or click submit on my add form page, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/r/14/3/ (or NoReverseMatch at /blogs/add/)

Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

If I go to mysite/blog/3 I do get the blog details page just fine as I have it set up. So I know the page works, but it seems like its not trying to find it since it says zero patterns tried.

Docs I'm looking at are:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

My code (what I think is relevant at least. If more info is needed let me know please)

blogs.models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from audit_log.models.fields import CreatingUserField, CreatingSessionKeyField

class Blog(models.Model):
    created_by = CreatingUserField(related_name = "created_categories")
    created_with_session_key = CreatingSessionKeyField()
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog_title = models.CharField('Blog Title', max_length=200)
    short_description = models.TextField('Short Description', max_length=140)
    blog_image = models.CharField('Image', max_length=200)
    youtube_link = models.URLField('YouTube', max_length=200)
    external_site_link = models.URLField('Website', max_length=200)
    full_blog = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.blog_name
```

urls.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blogs/', include('blogs.urls', namespace='blogs')),
)
```

blogs.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from blogs import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex=r'^$',
        view=views.BlogListView.as_view(),
        name='blog_list'
    ),

    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        view=views.BlogDetailView.as_view(),
        name='blog_detail'
    ),

    url(
        regex=r'^add/$',
        view=views.BlogCreate.as_view(),
        name='blog_add'
    ),

    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        view=views.BlogUpdate.as_view(),
        name='blog_update'
    ),

    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',
        view=views.BlogDelete.as_view(),
        name='blog_delete'
    ),
)
```

blogs.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.views.generic import ListView

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

# Only authenticated users can access views using this.
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

from .models import Blog

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog

class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog

class BlogCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['blog title', 'short_description', 'blog_image',
              'youtube_link', 'external_site_link', 'full_blog']

class BlogUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['blog title', 'short_description', 'blog_image',
              'youtube_link', 'external_site_link', 'full_blog']

class BlogDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Blog
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_list')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to address url with namespace `blogs` like this:

```
return reverse('blogs:blog_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: That capital B was actually a typo(now corrected). I mostly copy/pasted but I guess editing stuff I accidentally changed that somehow(going to blame lack of sleep). Anyway I think I'm making progress with your help. I changed to 'blogs:blog_detail' and I don't get that error any more. However, now I'm taken to http://searchassist.verizon.com/blahblahblahblah. On the page it says Sorry, We could not find http It may be unavailable or may not exist. My site is local only at the moment and it does seem to try the correct local url first. So strange.

Comment: Ok I just tested adding a new blog and it worked perfectly. So now its just the view on site from admin page not working. Its doing what I described above with the searchassist verizon thing.

Comment: OK fixed my final little issue with the admin view on site button. I had to change my site domain name field. Now everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much doniyor. The namespace solved it.